# Java not calling component's overloaded paintComponent method

Tags: java, swing, paint, repaint

First this is part of a homework assignment to create a mosaic image generator.
I want the program to repaint in realtime as it finds a image and place it ontop of another (source image).

This is code to create the panel in my main function.

The last piece mypanel.create() is the mosaic logic.

```
myPanel = new mosiacPanel(sourceFile, sizePercent, pixesize,threads, imageList);
//test.setText(Integer.toString(myPanel.getWidth()));
JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("COS 226 MOSIAC OF AWESOMENESS BY SLUIPMOORD && ELEANORASAURUSS");
myPanel.setVisible( true );
myPanel.repaint();
frame2.add(myPanel);
if(myPanel.getWidth() > menubar.getWidth()){
    frame2.setSize(myPanel.getWidth() , myPanel.getHeight() + menubar.getHeight() );
    frame2.repaint();
} else {
    frame2.setSize(menubar.getWidth() , myPanel.getHeight() + menubar.getHeight() );
}
frame2.setVisible( true );
//  myPanel.setLocation(170, 4);
myPanel.create();
```

Mosaic panel class code snippet

```
public void create()
{
    ph.createMosiac(imgUrls, this);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent( Graphics g ) 
{  super.paintComponent(g); 
   g.drawImage( imgToPaint, 0, 0, null );
   // System.out.println("paint");
}

public void paintTile( BufferedImage img ) 
{

    imgToPaint = img;        
    this.repaint();
    // this.paintComponent(this.getGraphics());
}
```

I call the paintTile function within create Mosaic Function.

```
public void createMosiac(List<String> fileNames, mosiacPanel parent)
{
    ArrayList<TileImage> srcTiles = new ArrayList<TileImage>();

    for( int i = 0; i < fileNames.size(); i++ ) 
    {
        srcTiles.add( new TileImage( fileNames.get(i), tileSize ) );
    }

    for( int y = 0; y <= (this.getHeight() - tileSize); y += tileSize ) 
    {           
        for( int x = 0; x <= (this.getWidth() - tileSize); x += tileSize ) 
        {
            int location = 0;
            double  dist, high = 2147483647;
            for( int i = 0; i < srcTiles.size(); i++ ) 
            {
                dist = this.getTileImage(x, y).differance( srcTiles.get(i) );

                if( (dist < high) )
                {
                    high = dist;
                    location = i;
                }                       
            }

            this.setTileImage( x, y, srcTiles.get(location) );
            parent.paintTile(this);                   
        }            
    }                        
}
```

That is my program logic.
When I uncomment this in the second snippet // this.paintComponent(this.getGraphics());
The program work but it repaints with a horrible flash and i am not one for medical bills when some of my other students within the demo venue are prone to epileptic attacks.

If I trace trace the paintComponent function it get called twice at the end of the program and not on every repaint.

Thank you in advance.

I added a source code you guys can just copy and run.
Select a image you want to test with the default is not available currently because you guys don't have it

and then a directory containing a bunch of jpg to tile it with 
It is pretty slow at the moment i still need to fix that
[Google docs link to the java file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1QbUvYjuQe1LUVDR1NQZlJzQms/edit)

Comment: For better help sooner, please include an [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: You should not be calling `paintComponent(...)` directly nor should you be using `getGraphics()` on a component to get the Graphics object. Instead use the Graphics object from the JVM (unless you're working with a BufferedImage's Graphics object). The Swing graphics tutorials explains all of this.

Comment: Wonder how this `parent.paintTile(this)` compile?

Comment: Hello I am working with Buffered Images. I am aware of the fact that i should not call paintComponetn directly

Comment: *"I am working with Buffered Images."* All would be obvious in an SSCCE.

Comment: Sorry but on this line: `this.paintComponent(this.getGraphics());` you are not getting a Graphics object from a BufferedImage but rather from a JComponent. I second the request for an [sscce](http://sscce.org), else we're all just wasting time debating.

Comment: Sorry i am confused about the sccee thing or the format exactly so here is a link to the code https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1QbUvYjuQe1LUVDR1NQZlJzQms/edit from google docs. i know that this.paintComponent(this.getGraphics()); doing that is not correct it was just a test to see what happened

Comment: @Gerhard: Since you're asking for free advice, it's not asking too much for you to put as much effort into asking the question as we would need to put in answering it. That means the onus is on you to extract the pertinent information from your larger code base and create an sscce for us and post it here rather than making us do it for ourselves. Do this and we'd appreciate your effort and you'd likely get an answer sooner.

Comment: While i was removing some of the elements(the menu bar) so that i can post an sscce it all of a sudden worked with out explicitly calling this.paintComponent(this.getGraphics());. The previous link i posted was all one file which you can copy and past or just download and compile, i posted it there because the code blocks here  broke a bit with the comments i am not sure why

Comment: So your code is now working and your problem has been solved? I am hopeful that this has occurred.

Comment: yes i did manage to find a way to let my overloaded paint method do its thing. not what i wanted initially but atleast i'm not doing stuff like this >> this.paintComponent(this.getGraphics());

Comment: @RNJ: read the description of the homework tag.

Comment: Thanks @Wug. Didnt realise that it was deprecated

Comment: @RNJ: I didn't either until I was about to retag a question with it, saw the description, did about a quadruple take, and searched on meta for relevant threads, then I finally believed I wasn't crazy.

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, you should post it here and accept it. Answering your own question is important so that people don't spend time trying to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

try the repainting in an other thread. Maybe this will be solve your problem.
Good Luck! :)